# Can rpart have 3 branch decision ? or other way?

Tags: r, decision-tree

So I tried to compare from rapidminer get this
[image]

But when I used R with rpart I got only 2 branch, can I get 3 just like rapidminer?

```
keks = read.csv("data.csv")

library(rpart)
tree <- rpart(transport ~ gender+car+travel+income, keks, method="class", minsplit = 3)
summary(tree)


library(rattle)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RColorBrewer)

fancyRpartPlot(tree)
```

the csv:

```
gender,car,travel,income,transport
Male,0,Cheap,Low,Bus
Male,1,Cheap,Medium,Train
Female,1,Cheap,Medium,Train
Female,0,Cheap,Low,Bus
Male,1,Cheap,Medium,Bus
Male,0,Standard,Medium,Train
Female,1,Standard,Medium,Train
Female,1,Expensive,High,Car
Male,2,Expensive,Medium,Car
Female,2,Expensive,High,Car
```

[image]

Comment: What's "rapidminer"? What type of model did you fit in that program? If you read the `rpart` introduction (`vignette("longintro","rpart")`) you'll see that `rpart` makes binary (two branch) classification trees. If you recommendations on statistical methods to use to classify your data, you should ask suck questions at [stats.se] since this really doesn't seem like a specific programming question that would be good for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you for your attention, cross validated is next then

Comment: `rpart` will always grow 2 branches from a node. Please check in rapidminer ; if you are growing trees where 3 branches are allowed like `CHAID` etc.